# Code of customized video media player in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, customization, media

I am getting Permission denied and NullPointerException in following URL code at line when new temporary file is created when streams of bytes are downloaded in that file in the `getDataSource()` at `File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");`.

The Wi-Fi, Internet, and ExternalStorage permissions are added in manifest file.Is there I am missing any more permissions or any settings or any code?

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/android-–-videomusic-player-sample-take-2/

Answer (score 1):

At last i got my my code solution by my self..
i needed to install sdcard image on emulator..the above errors where coming because it was not getting its internal memory to create temporary file..
Now my code is running fine...